# Value of type 'ObservedObject<TimerStructManager>.Wrapper' has no dynamic member 'exerciseTime' using key path from root type 'TimerStructManager'

Tags: swift, swiftui, persistence

I am making an exercise app and I want to implement persistence so that users cant rack how much exercise they have gotten done for the day and I want that data to persist.

I created a manager to manage the data from the TimerStruct, which is where the total time for exercise comes from but when I try to implment it into my home screen view, I keep getting this error.

Value of type 'ObservedObject<TimerStructManager>.Wrapper' has no dynamic member 'exerciseTime' using key path from root type 'TimerStructManager' and Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Subject>' to expected argument type 'Int' at this line.

```
let percent = Double($timer.exerciseTime/1500)
```

TimerStruct:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TimerStruct: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var exerciseTime = 0.0
     var isAlertpresented = false
     var countdownTimer = 300
     var timerRunning = false
     var isPaused = false
     var isActive = false
    var isCompleted = false
}
```

TimerManager:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class TimerStructManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var timerStructs: [TimerStruct] = [] {
        didSet {
            save()
        }
    }
    
    let sampleTimerStructs: [TimerStruct] = []
    
    init() {
        load()
    }
    
    func getArchiveURL() -> URL {
        let plistName = "timerStructs.plist"
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        
        return documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(plistName)
    }
    
    func save() {
        let archiveURL = getArchiveURL()
        let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        let encodedTimerStructs = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(timerStructs)
        try? encodedTimerStructs?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)
    }
    
    func load() {
        let archiveURL = getArchiveURL()
        let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        
        var finalTimerStructs: [TimerStruct]!
        
        if let retrievedTimerStructData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL),
           let decodedTimerStructs = try? propertyListDecoder.decode([TimerStruct].self, from: retrievedTimerStructData) {
            finalTimerStructs = decodedTimerStructs
        } else {
            finalTimerStructs = sampleTimerStructs
        }
        
        timerStructs = finalTimerStructs
    }
}
```

HomeScreen

```
import AVKit
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var timer: TimerStructManager
    @Binding var streak: Streaks
    @Binding var timerStruct: TimerStruct
    @State var isSheetPresented = false
    @Binding var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    @Binding var exercisePlans: [ExercisePlan]
    
    func ridzero(result: Double) -> String {
        let value = String(format: "%g", result)
        return value
    }
    func round(result: Double) -> String {
        let value = String(format: "%.1f", result)
        return value
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        //NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView {
                    ZStack {
                        VStack {
                            
                            let percent = Double($timer.exerciseTime/1500)
                            Text("Welcome back to ElderlyFit")
                                .font(.system(size: 25,weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                                .offset(x: 0, y: 20)
                            
                            CircularProgressView(timer: $timerStruct, progress: CGFloat(percent))
                                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                                .offset(x: -95, y: -240)
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 280, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                            Text("\(round(result:percent*100))%")
                                .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                                .offset(x:-92, y:-345)
                            
                            Text("\(round(result: $timer.exerciseTime/60)) mins of exercise completed today")
                                .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                                .font(.system(size: 20, design: .rounded))
                                .offset(x:100, y:-440)
                            
                            Button {
                                
                                navigationPath.append("ExercisePlanDetailView")
                                
                            } label: {
                                Text("Start exercise")
                            }
                            .padding()
                            .background((Color(red: 184/255, green: 243/255, blue: 255/255)))
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .offset(x: 92, y: -430)
                            .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
                            
                            
                            StreaksView(timer: $timerStruct, streak: $streak)
                                .offset(x:0, y: -370)
                                .padding()
                            
                            Text("Choose your exercise plan:")
                                .bold()
                                .font(.system(size: 25))
                                .offset(x: -30, y: -450)
                                .zIndex(1.0)
                            
                            
                            ExercisePlanView( streaks: $streak, timer: $timerStruct, navigationPath: $navigationPath, exercisePlans: $exercisePlans)
                                .offset(x: 15, y: -430)
                                .zIndex(-1.0)
                                .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 15)))
                            
                        }
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        
                    }
                    //                    .background(Color("appBackground"))
                    //                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }
            }
        }
        //.navigationTitle("Home")
    }
```

Comment: `TimerStructManager` doesn't have a variable named `exerciseTime`. `TimerStruct` has. `timer` is of type `TimeStructManager`.

Comment: yea but TimerStructManager is the data manager for TimerStruct so shouldn't it have the variable

Comment: The structs and classes have the variables that you declare. And it's impossible for the class `TimeStructManager` to have automatically a variable from the struct `TimeStruct`: what value will it hold, given that the class contains an array of the structs? You need to explicitly tell what the variable `TimeStructManager.exerciseTime` should restore.

Comment: How would I explicitly tell it what to restore?

Comment: The manager doesn’t have the variable but each object in the array has it. You need a loop to get the variable